Send command from .NET Core application to Ubuntu WSL
I have a C# .NET Core 8 application that relies on a database in Windows 11 WSL (running Ubuntu).
Is there a way to send the startup command to WSL automatically from the application (ideally on application launch)?
It's a bit tedious to do it manually every time I need to use my application. Looked around for any clues, but no idea - I'm new to this type of thing.
More specifically: the database is ClickHouse, and I'm sending the command from a WinUI3 application. I'm the only user, this runs locally and is never distributed to others. Security, etc. isn't a concern.
Thanks!

what command are you 'manually' using to start your clickhouse db?

Here's the steps I'm doing now:

From start menu, open the "Ubuntu" app. This shows the terminal.
Enter sudo service clickhouse-server start
Enter password when prompted


WSL is just a lightweight virtual machine running on your windows host machine.  You can start the VM with the wsl command. If your database is in a WSL distribution other than the default, you start is like this:
wsl -d distro_name
If you want your database process to start automatically when the machine starts, that must be configured inside the ubuntu system.
Most linux applications use systemd to automatically start daemon processes.  WSL did not support systemd until recently.  You may have to update WSL to a recent version and/or setup the configuration to get systemd working.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/systemd

Alright, I see. Thanks!
